# How to find a row in an Excel sheet using Excel Macro VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, counter

[image]

My code for now is:

```
Set RecT = gConnect.Execute("SELECT [Volume] FROM [Output$] WHERE ((([Facilities])=""IDK"") AND (([Detail_1])=""BPL"" Or ([Detail_1])=""SI"")) ORDER BY [Detail_1];")
Worksheets("Results").Cells(52, 4).CopyFromRecordset RecT
```

First, with `Set Rect` I look for the value I want in another sheet, and then I copy it in the 4th column of the 52nd row of my sheet 'Results' ( the one in the picture). But instead of giving it the exact indexes, I want it to find that cell.
As you can see in the photo, I have to find the line where Column A = traitement, Column B = IDK and Column C = BPL.

I looked it up and found that i have to use `Cells.Find` , but I can't understand how to do that !

Comment: If you only work on an excel sheet, why are you using queries? If you want to find a row with these contents, you'd just have to iterate through the rows and check the regarding columns.

Comment: @EngJon (I edited my question to make it clearer) But how can I iterate through the rows and check the columns ?

Comment: If it's only that, I can write an answer. Well there already is an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim compteur As Long
Dim lineFound As Boolean

'Load range contents to array
v = Range("A1:C7").Value 'Or wherever your data is

'Iterate through array until desired content found
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    If v(i, 1) = "traitement" And v(i, 2) = "IDK" And v(i, 3) = "BPL" Then
        compteur = i
        lineFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'Report
If lineFound Then
    MsgBox "The thing you want is on line " & compteur
Else
    MsgBox "Didn't find the thing you want."
End If
```

Comment: Great, I get the trick. Can you explain the `v = Range("A1:C7").Value` a little more? What does v contain ?

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in the debugger and have a look for yourself! You will find that far more instructive and convincing than anything I can write here in a comment.